# Can dismax & the standard Solr search handler be used together in the same query

Tags: solr

Can dismax & the standard Solr search handler be used together in the same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this:

http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/03/31/nested-queries-in-solr/